# Honeypot protection not working

Tags: php, html

I've made a very simple little example code that is supposed to protect my form from bots. But it sends the form even when I unhide the input via developers tools and put text in the value of the input.

This is the code I use:

(index.html file)

```
 <li>
     <input type="text" name="bot" value="" class="hidden" />
 </li>
```

(mail.php file)

```
if (isset($_POST['bot']) && !empty($_POST['bot'])) {
    die();
}
```

(if more of the code is needed, feel free to tell me)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this bot input protects your form?

Comment: Bots are very good at figuring this stuff out, especially if the botmaker is specifically targeting your site. Use a proper captcha like https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/.

Comment: @MehdiBounya Some bots attempt to fill out every field on a form. Having a hidden field that humans won't see used to be a common approach - it worked for a while, but most bots these days are capable of evaluating CSS/JS and ignoring hidden fields.

Comment: Visibly hidden or input type hidden fields are still submitted with form so isset() won't complain. Only disabled input fields are not sent to form but anyone can enable them via developers tool so this whole logic of protecting from bot by hiding a field is useless and flawed.

Comment: Thanks to @ceejayoz now I understand your technique, but like the others said it's kinda useless, using a recaptcha is way better

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

Don't.

**Because:**

What your code does is it sends the hidden field regardless of who submits the form, bot or human.

Your approach would be better IF, for example, you had created a HUMAN input with javascript onPageLoad, filled with a session generated token.

But still, it won't help you much with bots. They ain't be dumb, ya'know.

```
// my silly dumb anti-bot protection
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(form).append('<input type=hidden name=probably_human value='+<?php echo $_SESSION['token'] ?>+'>');
})

<?php
if (!isset($_POST['probably_human']){
    die;
}
if ($_POST['probably_human'] != $_SESSION['token']){
    die;
}
```

And even here, I can boot-up a [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), [nightmarejs](http://www.nightmarejs.org/), [electron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YP_nOCO-4Q) and automate the crap out of your honeypot.

---

Have you tried [recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/)?

Stick to the solutions provided by specialists, experts in the field of anti-bot protection. People who are getting paid for making sure, they know how to distinguish between a bot and a human.